# Python Selenium Popup

Tags: html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
# Setup

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchAttributeException, NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)




driver.get("https://am1.badoo.com/sv/mobile/")
driver.maximize_window()

username = "*************"
password = "*************"
print(driver.title)
time.sleep(5)

search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/a')
search = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Logga in')
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(5)

print("Login in")
search = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
search.send_keys(username)
search = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
search.send_keys(password)

time.sleep(2)
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page"]/div[1]/div[3]/section/div/div/div[1]/form/div[5]/div/div[1]/button').click()
time.sleep(5)
# klickar på like knappen
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mm_cc"]/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]').click()
time.sleep(1)

#popup
#Switch the control to the Alert window
search = driver.switch_to.alert

#Retrieve the message on the Alert window
message=search.text
print ("Alert shows following message: "+ message )
time.sleep(2)
# Or Dismiss the Alert using
search.dismiss()
```

Hey my question is that I cant understand how to handle a popup. Trying to make a automation for badoo the dating application. And when you like the first person a popup appers. But I cant find or firgure out how to connect that popup so I can click decline/ accept.

Can any one help me out?

Thanks in advance :)

Screen of popup:

[image]

Can't figure out how to copy html code, but this is screens of it:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you share HTML code ? we cannot login to random website.

Comment: Wasen't Abel to copy the html code from the page, but i added screens of it. with the popup part high lighted. Hops it help to understand my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the popup has the same text and format every single time, you can use pyautogui(python library) to detect the popup and move the mouse to the position of "Nej" and click it.